# PHP file download with mod-xsendfile does not download entire file

Tags: php, download, varnish, x-sendfile

I am having problem serving downloads from our website. Large files just won't download in full. Download will stop somewhere in between... Example [this file](http://dewesoft.com/download?file=DEWESoft_FULL_7_0_5.exe) (size cca 172MB) won't download in full size (there are other files also).

I switched from entirely PHP-base download script, the one included in Kohana framework:

`return download::force($filePath);`

to a mod-xsendfile solution. I was reading about the possible problems with PHP based download scripts and large file and cam over mod-xsendfile is the right solution... Well looks like not, I am getting the same result with both techniques. My current download implementation using mod-xsendfile headers like this:

```
header("X-Sendfile: $filePath");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"');
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I used [this HTTP sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) to check response headers and this is the result if it helps solving this problem.

```
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache  
Set-Cookie: dewesoftsession=63ms5j67kc231pr4bpm8cmg1f7; expires=Sat, 30-Mar-2013 11:36:59 GMT; path=/   
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0   
Pragma: no-cache    
Set-Cookie: dewesoftsession=63ms5j67kc231pr4bpm8cmg1f7; expires=Sat, 30-Mar-2013 11:36:59 GMT; path=/   
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DEWESoft_FULL_7_0_5.exe" 
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Sep 2012 12:50:12 GMT    
ETag: "25814de-ac291e9-4ca7207c7fcd9"   
Content-Type: application/octet-stream  
Content-Length: 180523497   
Date: Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:37:01 GMT 
X-Varnish: 294312007    
Age: 2  
Via: 1.1 varnish    
Connection: close   
X-Varnish-Cache: MISS
```

Comment: What are the response headers that you get from the server?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Using the developer tools of your browser; under the network tab.

Comment: I don't see anything, try yourself I have linked the file above which triggers download script: http://dewesoft.com/download?file=DEWESoft_FULL_7_0_5.exe

Comment: @Jack I have updated my question with response headers

Comment: Those headers look fine actually. Perhaps it's Varnish?

Comment: I have no clues what Varnish is? We have managed server so I just handle the website files...

Comment: @Jack I have spoken to system guys @ my hosting provider and we have excluded my download script from Varnish, the problem you have suggested. Unfortunately this did not help and the problem still exists. Apache and Varnish were restarted after Varnish configuration update... Now I am running out of my ideas :-(.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if adding header('Cache: private'); may help here. Otherwise the headers look fine. The Apache logs don't reveal anything do they?

Comment: @Jack tried adding the header you suggested (I have added it before `header("X-Sendfile: $filePath");`) -> same result. Apache logs are empty...

Comment: @Jack just figured out it works normally for most users, but for me the download is broken. Is it possible that there's an error only on my side? Some kind of timeout or what. I tried different browsers, wget and curl and the download is always broken before entire file gets down... I don't know running out of ideas. I can download normally bigger files from other sites :S!

Comment: Wish I could tell you what it is, but it's starting to look like either your ISP or PC is messing with you :)

Comment: @Jack just figured out that Varnish has a startup parameter called send_timeout which is set to 600s by default. This has caused the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of days we managed to find what cause the problem. Varnish has a start-up parameter called `send_timeout` which is set to 600s by default. With large file downloads you might run into this timeout which will cause your download to be interrupted.

So increasing Varnish's `send_timeout` parameter will help you solve this kind of issue.